# How to make the links in Javascript code nofollow

Tags: javascript

I want to make the links in this javascript code **nofollow**. Please help me how to do that.

```js
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank');"><img src="https://example.png/></a>
```

Comment: `<a ... rel="nofollow">...</a>` ?

Comment: Hint: if `href` is blank, it's not a link.

Comment: Will that come inside onclick or outside

Comment: The op wants to trigger links in js with the nofollow attribute set and has provided a minimal working example.

Comment: @MJHaider Outside, as an attribute.

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank');" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://example.png/></a>

Comment: @JasonB - Please check if this is correct

Comment: @JasonB - This code is for new window. What should I replace if I want the to open in new tab??

Comment: When you just use target="_blank" in an a tag without the javascript the browser will open the link in a new browser context which will be a tab or window depending on the user's device, browser, and settings. I believe that this is the commonly accepted best practice

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open you can add a third parameter in the window.open method that is a comma separated string with name value pairs - but rel is not supported...

Seems like html may be a good option.

```
<a href="www.example.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" >Link</a>
```

If you need to do this from js you could trigger a click on the link.

Comment: Thanks Jason for that.

Comment: [`rel` is not one of the features supported by `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features).

Comment: But it is supported by <a href, am I right?